# refreshing an nsfetchedresultscontroller not tied to a uitableview

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i am wrting an app that uses a number of `NSFetchedResultsControllers` (FRCs), each for a different Managed Object subclass in my data model.  several of these FRCs are part of `UITableViewControllers`, but several are not.  i have two questions: one, why is one of my FRCs not updating when i add a new object to the MOC, and two, should i be using an FRC at all for this purpose?  i thought it would save me from having to put fetch requests in all over the code, but perhaps it only makes sense to use an FRC with a `tableview` or other such object.

so, here are the details.

one of the FRCs not tied to a `tableview` is one that keeps track of schedules. the SetScheduleViewController has the following properties (among others), which are passed in via the parent view controller:

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *scheduleFetchedResultsController;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

this FRC was created by another object (which maintains a strong pointer to it) via the following code

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)scheduleFetchedResultsController  {


    if (_scheduleFetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _scheduleFetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Schedule" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *fRC = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fRC performFetch:&error]) {
        IFLErrorHandler *errorHandler;
        [errorHandler reportErrorToUser:error];
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    self.scheduleFetchedResultsController = fRC;

    return self.scheduleFetchedResultsController;
}
```

(an aside: the reason the cacheName is set to nil is that i seem to be able to assign a cache name to only one of the many FRCs in this app, or the app crashes...if only one FRC is given a cache name and the rest have cache names set to nil, all seems well, though i am concerned that without a cache the performance may be terrible as the size of the persistent store grows...but that's another matter)

within the `SetScheduleViewController`, a schedule can be created or deleted, and on loading the `SetScheduleViewController` the most recently created schedule is loaded.  when a schedule is created a new Schedule Managed Object is created, and then the MOC is saved as follows:

```
 Schedule *newSchedule= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Schedule" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 newSchedule.start=newStartTime; 
 //etc

  NSError *saveError;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", saveError, [saveError userInfo]);
        abort();
```

this successfully saves the new MO, but the FRC does not update...i've checked this several ways...for example, if after saving a new schedule i re-enter the `SetScheduleViewController` and check `[[self.scheduleFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` count] it is not incremented.  however, if i quit the app and open it again, lo and behold, the FRC fetched object count is incremented and the new object is indeed there.

i should note that the `scheduleFetchedResultsController` does not have a delegate assigned, unlike the FRC's attached to `tableviewcontrollers`, which are all working fine.  i didn't assign a delegate because from what i could tell, the FRC delegate methods in the `tableviewcontrollers` only deal with updating the tableview when the FRC changes content...i do not see any delegate methods that refresh the FRC itself when a new object is added and the MOC saved.

so, my two questions again are: 1) why is the FRC not refreshing (and how can i make it refresh), 2) does it even make sense to use an FRC to manage fetched results for a managed object not tied to a `tableview`, and should i instead simply perform a fresh fetch from the MOC every time i need access to the list of objects?

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same problem before. The reason is you didn't performed the fetch of FRC.
Add the following code on -viewDidLoad:

```
NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: Look again, he does have a performFetch: call.

Comment: actually, i tried Aditya's suggestion and this fixed it...i don't know how to undo someone's down vote (i don't have enough reputation points to even vote myself), but this does fix the problem.  re: what Kendall says, i perform the fetch request in the getter, but it isn't called there if the FRC already exists (at least, i think that's the problem...either that or the getter isn't being called, though that shouldn't be the case)...bottom line: putting the performFetch in the viewDidLoad of SetScheduleViewController works...would like to understand why.

Comment: ps. it should be noted that i tried Aditya's suggestion AFTER putting the FRC in tracking mode by assigning a delegate and adding an empty controllerDidChangeContent method in that delegate, as suggested by Martin...but i just commented out the delegate assignment and things *still* work thanks to Aditya's code...that is *very* puzzling to me as without the delegate assignment the FRC should not be in tracking mode per Apple, as Martin points out

Answer (score 3):

In the `NSFetchedResultsController` documentation it is stated that the FRC is in "no-tracking" mode if no delegate has been set. Also, the delegate must implement at least one of the change tracking delegate methods in order for change tracking to be enabled.

The delegate does not have to be a table view controller, so you could use your 
`SetScheduleViewController` as a delegate and just implement the `controllerDidChangeContent:` delegate method. Inside that method, the updated
`fetchedObjects` is available, and you can e.g. update any UI elements in the view
controller.

*Update:* Passing the FRC from the parentVC does not make much sense. *Each view controller should have its own FRC*. So `scheduleFetchedResultsController` should be a method in the childVC. And as the FRC is created "lazily" in the getter method, the getter has to be called somewhere.

In the case of table view controllers, this happens because all table view data source methods
access `self.fetchedResultsController`.

If your childVC does not access `self.fetchedResultsController` then the FRC
will not be created. That could be the reason why calling `[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]` in `viewDidLoad`, as suggested in the other answer, solved your problem.

The delegate method `controllerDidChangeContent:` will then be called if the result
set changes *during the lifetime of the childVC*. That's where using an FRC makes sense.

If you just want to fetch the current set of objects when the childVC is loaded then
you don't need a FRC, and you can just execute a simple fetch, e.g. in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: thanks for pointing the issue out, but i still can't get it to work.  when i create the scheduleFetchedResultsController i set the the delegate to the object that created it (after declaring that object an NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate).  the Apple documentation states "Important: A delegate must implement at least one of the change tracking delegate methods in order for change tracking to be enabled. Providing an empty implementation of controllerDidChangeContent: is sufficient."  so i did exactly that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @daveadelson: Calling performFetch updates the fetchedObjects in any case (even in the no-tracking mode). The tracking mode *should* work as well. You could set a breakpoint in the getter method to find out when it is called. It is a "lazy getter" method, a common pattern is to set `self.fetchedResultsController = nil` to force the recreation.  And why are the FRC and context properties weak? - But anyway, your problem seems to be solved now, and that is fine.

Comment: doesn't setting the FRC to nil sort of defeat the purpose of having an FRC?  ...as to the problem being solved, if i don't understand it i am not at all comfortable using it going forward...i'd like to figure it out.  as to the FRC properties being weak, i assumed that because the parent had a strong pointer to them i should have weak pointers from any children VCs to which they were passed.  is this incorrect?

Comment: ps. i did put a breakpoint in the getter and it wasn't being called at all, other than when the FRC was first created by the parentVC

Comment: @daveadelson: My last comment was a bit misleading. I have updated the answer with more information that might be useful.

Comment: i use the various FRC's throughout the app, so rather than make them in every object that needs to access them i just created them once and passed them to the various children that need access to them...i assumed that this was a better way to do it than to have each object that needs access to the FRC make its own.

Comment: @daveadelson: I don't think that passing the FRC around is a good solution. In particular, the FRC has only a single delegate. How would that work with table view controllers and other view controllers sharing the FRC? - So thinking about it, sharing the FRC seems to be the main problem in your case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43236/discussion-between-dave-adelson-and-martin-r)

Comment: Men I owe you a lot of beer. With pointing out that "without delegate nothing will be tracked" you saved my day. I really don't know how I forgot to set delegate :)